# How to interpret color intensity in displot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, displot

I am new to seaborn, and I was going through documentation and examples. I have attached the plot below. How can we interpret the color intensity in this plot?

[image]

Comment: The best way would be to add a `cbar=True` argument in displot. Please see figure #6 in https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html#visualizing-bivariate-distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will not be able to really understand what those bluish colours mean unless there is a scale or a guide which represents the mapping of colors to some attributes of the data.

Thus, the best way to do this would be to add a `cbar=True` argument in [`sns.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html#visualizing-bivariate-distributions), along with the title of the colorbar to make sure the visualisation conveys the context properly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")

sns.displot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", cbar=True,
cbar_kws={'label': 'Counts in the bin'})

plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image]